# Why can't my KML file display in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am new to HTML and KML. Can anyone take a look at my code? It doesn't display in Google Maps. It immediately prompts up to download when I search the url. Is there something wrong with the host? or there is an error in KML file. Below is the complete code.

```
    <script>

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {lat: 45.876, lng: 255.624}
    });

    var retailersM = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'https://sites.google.com/a/daneson.com/stuff/home/kmlstuff/1.kml',
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included the google maps script? Have you defined the `map` variable? What error do you get in your browser console? It looks like access to your KML file requires a login.

Comment: Yes, the google map displays correctly.   when I access my KML file it was automatically downloaded. I thought it means publically available.  Do you know elsewhere that I can put my file?

Comment: I copied my codes from Google's tutorial, there shouldn't be a problem. I exported the KML from GoogleMyMap, so the KML file is ok too. I tried to upload it to dropbox and google drive and take public link as URL source, they all didn't work..

Comment: Thanks for the update. Would you mind [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37954419/edit) to update it with that new information? It may help if you can include the complete code so that we can try to reproduce the problem. For example, the code you posted does not include the google maps script or definition of the `map` variable.